# Is that possible to connect Salesforce through Eclipse IDE without a security token?

Tags: eclipse, security-token

i tried to connect Salesforce through Eclipse with adding a security token and it throws error. But one of my pal using clients sandbox and he said he logging in Eclipse without a security token. Is that possible to connect Salesforce through Eclipse IDE without a security token?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is. You need to add your IP address range into `Setup->Security Controls->Network Access` and then you don't need to use the security token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as i said above, he logs in from any network (new IPs not registered in Network Access in salesforce) and still able to use salesforce in his Eclipse without a security token. i'm wondering how it could be achieved?

Comment: I doubt they're logging in without having the IP whitelisted and without security token. At least not with the Eclipse IDE... If an IP address is not whitelisted, they must provide a security token - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_loginrestrict.htm&language=en

Comment: Hesitated to ask the client to find how they configured that...also, there is no IP range whitelisted in Network access. Do we need to call salesforce.com to configure something like that? I am awaiting for more suggestions here...

Comment: Please confirm that there are no login IP Ranges added for the user's profile (not the org) and also this is not checked in the profile's permissions " Two-Factor Authentication for API Logins".

Comment: Look under your personal profile settings to see what your last login IP address was. Copy that and add it to Trusted IP Ranges and you should be okay.

Comment: Which IP Range do we need to put there ?

Answer (score -1):

Don't add the token to the end of the password, that has changed in 2015. The token that you are issued is the only thing that goes in the token field. I lost hours based on bad posts!